# How to get dynamically created checkboxes' value

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, webforms

I have a Users table in my Webforms ASP.NET 4.5 application which is filled dynamically with users. In that table there are checkboxes before the each username. I want to delete all the users which i checked after i click a delete button. However, when i click delete button, although button clicked event is called, checkedchanged event of checked checkboxes is not called. How can i get these checked checkboxes' value when i click the delete button?

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3.Account
{
    public partial class Register : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private UserStore<IdentityUser> userStore;
        private UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager;
        private List<string> users = new List<string>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(userStore);
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fillTable();
            } 
        }

        private void fillTable()
        {
            TableHeaderRow headerRow = new TableHeaderRow();
            TableHeaderCell hCell1 = new TableHeaderCell();
            hCell1.CssClass = "col-md-1";
            hCell1.Text = "#";
            TableHeaderCell hCell2 = new TableHeaderCell();
            hCell2.Text = "Kullanıcı Adı";
            hCell2.CssClass = "col-md-5";
            headerRow.Controls.Add(hCell1);
            headerRow.Controls.Add(hCell2);
            headerRow.Controls.Add(new TableHeaderCell() { CssClass = "col-md-3" });
            headerRow.Controls.Add(new TableHeaderCell() { CssClass = "col-md-3" });
            headerRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
            tblUser.Rows.Add(headerRow);

            foreach (IdentityUser user in userManager.Users.ToList())
            {
                TableRow row = new TableRow();
                TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();
                CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox();
                checkBox.InputAttributes.Add("value", user.Id);
                checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
                cell1.Controls.Add(checkBox);
                cell1.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                TableCell cell2 = new TableCell();
                cell2.Text = user.UserName;
                TableCell cell3 = new TableCell();
                HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
                link.Text = "Şifreyi Değiştir";
                cell3.Controls.Add(link);
                row.Controls.Add(cell1);
                row.Controls.Add(cell2);
                row.Controls.Add(new TableCell());
                row.Controls.Add(cell3);
                tblUser.Rows.Add(row);
                row.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableBody;
            }
        }

        void checkBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ViewState["userList"] != null)
            {
                users = (List<string>)ViewState["userList"];
            }
            CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox)sender;
            if (checkbox.Checked)
            {
                if (!users.Contains(checkbox.InputAttributes["value"]))
                {
                    users.Add(checkbox.InputAttributes["value"]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (users.Contains(checkbox.InputAttributes["value"]))
                {
                    users.Remove(checkbox.InputAttributes["value"]);
                }
            }

            ViewState["userList"] = users;
        }

        protected void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (string id in users)
            {
                IdentityUser user = userManager.FindById(id);
                userManager.Delete(user);
            }
            fillTable();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: is there  any feedback ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
foreach(TableRow row in tblUser) 
{
    foreach(TableCell cell in row) 
    {
        foreach(Control ctrl in cell) 
        {
            if (ctrl.GetType() == CheckBox) 
            {
                /* get value here */
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your ByttonClickEvent

```
protected void btnDeleteUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
foreach(var row in tblUser.Rows)
 {
   var tempcheckBox= row.Controls[0] as CheckBox;
   if(tempcheckBox.IsChecked)
    {
       //your code
    }
 }
}
```

row.Controls[0] because the checkbox is inserted inside the first column
Move the dataBinding process in `Page_LoadComplete` method and
remove the test `if(!IsPostBack)`.

Infact if you invoke a postBack you go first by Pre_Init , PageLoad ,Your EventHandler and then Page_Load Complete.

So if your binding process is done in the Page_Load. Automatically you will find your gridView in your eventHandler as it was initilised in PageLoad.

Comment: tblUser returns 0 row

Comment: it is 0 because of this code in page Load `if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                fillTable();
            } `

Comment: In every Check_event you made a postback and you don't update tblUser dataSource that's why count = 0

Comment: i removed if(!IsPostBack) but it works only first time after then checkbox.Checked returns false although it is checked

Answer (score 0):

Remove below line from your foreach loop where you creating dynamic checkbox list:

```
checkBox.CheckedChanged += checkBox_CheckedChanged;
```

Please add below lines instead of above line:

```
checkBox.Attributes.Add("name", "chkDel");
checkBox.Attributes.Add("onclick", "UncheckDelAll('chkDelAll','chkDel')");
```

Put down below javascript in top of your page:

```
function UncheckDelAll(HeaderChk, RowChk) {

        var cnt = 0; //Count of all the check boxes
        objSelected = document.getElementsByName(HeaderChk)
        obj = document.getElementsByName(RowChk)
        if (obj != null) {
            cnt = obj.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
                if (obj[i].checked == true);
                cnt = 1;

            }
            if (cnt == 1)
                objSelected[0].checked = false;

        }
    }
```

Here is the delete button click event logic:

```
protected void lkDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string sPrimaryIds = (string)Request.Params["chkDel"];
// Write your delete query functionality over here
// Your delete query like this
// delete from [tablename] where UserId in (sPrimaryIds)
}
```